# Input textField not moving above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitabbarcontroller

Hi Im using JSQMessagesViewController SDK for a chat feature ,I don't think that my problem is linked to their SDK , when I entered the Chat controller and click on the textField the keyboard appears but not the TextField.

[image: textField is not moving above the textField]

my list of chats is embedded in a TabBarController. 
When I click on another tab and after that return to the chat ViewController the textField IS now moving above the keyboard as wanted...

[image: textField is Above the keyboard]

The bug is also happening when I calling the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate (to change the chat's photo) 
My code :

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        imageOfChat.image = image
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Here too , I can get ride off the bug by clicking on other tab in the TabBarController..

Is there a way to reproduce this "tab click" action programmatically?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Try to use `[textfield becomeFirstResponsoder];` in textfielddidbeginEditing.